# Set initdb and pg_ctl

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-initdb

I installed Postgresql from source.

I tried running the commands:

```
which initdb
which pg_ctl
```

but I get a blank response.

I know where these executables reside in my directory.

How might I set `initdb` and `pg_ctl`?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have received the blank output for command 'which', as these binaries are not known to your linux machine. And hence you will also need to run these binaries using './' (like ./pg_ctl)
You can add the path of your postgres bin directory to $PATH.

Eg.

> export PATH=$PATH:/Postgres/Installation/Path/bin/

You can also set it permanently by adding the above path value in .bash_profile file in home of directory of Postgres user.